# Pseudo random permutation for arbitrary size domains

Tags: symmetric, pseudo-random-permutation

Popular block ciphers like AES or Twofish are keyed pseudo random permutations on the domain $\{0,1,\dots,2^{k}-1\}$ with $k\in\{128,192,256\}$ or similar.

I'm interested in pseudo random permutations on domains whose size is not a power of two: Are there any fast (in the ballpark of AES) keyed pseudo random permutations that operate on $\{0,1,\dots,n\}$ with $n\in\mathbb{N}$ being an adjustable parameter?

Comment: What you search is [tag:format-preserving] encryption. It is generally slower than AES, though.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann using FPE with AES-NI is comparable speeds with AES-NI. Feistel networks with 10 or so rounds with AES-NI hardly slows it down .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Ciphers with Arbitrary Finite Domains by Black and Rogaway* have some options like Prefix Ciphers, Generalized Feistel networks , Cycle walking etc.

Also Format preserving encryption has traits that you are looking for , but NIST standardized ones are patented by Voltage Inc.

In general Feistel networks + Cycle walking would give a good option for any arbitrary length (even or odd) domains .

This question has much better answer 
[Is there a length-preserving encryption scheme?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/6098/is-there-a-length-preserving-encryption-scheme)

Comment: If I may extend the question of the OP the paper you cited states that their methods aren't suitable when the domain $X$ is such that $2^{30}<|X|<2^{60}$ and presents that gap as a open problem. Are you aware of subsequent research that solved ?

Comment: my last suggestion of , Feistel Networks + Cycle walking should help . please "PRP Luby Rack off revisited" by Naor and Reingold .

Comment: @AlexandreYamajako : $\:$ [Perfect Block Ciphers With Small Blocks](http://www.iacr.org/archive/fse2007/45930457/45930457.pdf) works in that gap. $\hspace{1.36 in}$