# All-or-nothing transform that doesn't increase message size?

Tags: blocksize, avalanche, aont

All of the AON transforms I've read about involve generating a key, which increases the message by a few bytes. Is there an AON transform that preserves the message size while still having avalanche properties?

Comment: **Related:** ["Length-preserving all-or-nothing transform"](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/17742/), SE.Crypto.